# how to display message after loop is done when setTimeout is involved?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, geocoding

I am using google Geocode api to loop and geocode a list of 22 postcodes and store them into a DB. I would like to display a message when the geocoding is done, however as i have to use setTimeout to avoid running into the "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" error at 11 postcodes, my message is appearing much sooner than what the process actually takes. How can i resolve this?

JS

```
                function geocodeAddress (postcode) {
                    geocoder.geocode({'address': postcode}, function(results, status) {

                        if (status === 'OK') {
                            var x,
                                resultsLength = results.length;

                            for(x = 0; x < resultsLength; x++) {
                                lat = results[x].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(8);
                                lng = results[x].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(8);
                                //send values to php file
                                sendLatLng(lat, lng);
                            }
                        } 
                        else if (status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {
                            //call function again after delay when error is encountered
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                geocodeAddress(postcode);
                            }, 200);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('Geocode was not successful: ' + status);
                        } 
                    });
                };

                for (n = 0; n < pstcodeLength; n++) {
                    geocodeAddress(postcodes[n]);
                    //display message after loop is complete
                    if (n === pstcodeLength-1) {
                        console.log('geocoding is complete');
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You are saying `'geocoding is complete'` is happening too soon? Of course because the asynchronous requests are still running when the loop is complete.

Comment: Yes I know, is it possible to display after everything is done?

Comment: SO keep track of each one that is complete and when you hit the max, display the message.

Answer (score 0):

JUst keep track of the number that are complete. When you get the max, than show the message.

```
var cnt = 0;

function geocodeAddress(postcode) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': postcode
  }, function(results, status) {

    if (status === 'OK') {
      var x,
        resultsLength = results.length;

      for (x = 0; x < resultsLength; x++) {
        lat = results[x].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(8);
        lng = results[x].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(8);
        //send values to php file
        sendLatLng(lat, lng);
      }
      cnt++;
    } else if (status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {
      //call function again after delay when error is encountered
      setTimeout(function() {
        geocodeAddress(postcode);
      }, 200);
    } else {
      cnt++;
      console.log('Geocode was not successful: ' + status);
    }

    if (cnt === pstcodeLength) {
      console.log('geocoding is complete');
    }
  });
};
```